# How to get assigned template name in onAfterInitialise?

Tags: development, plugin

This seems like a bug  and I tested on both 2.5.x and 3.x but there is no way to get assigned template name in `onAfterInitialise` by using

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$templatename =  $app->getTemplate();
    echo $templatename;
```

What it actually does once you call `$app->getTemplate()` it switches your assigned template to default one.

In my system plugin I do this

```
public function onAfterInitialise() {

    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $templatename =  $app->getTemplate();
    echo $templatename;

}
```

It works fine if I use it in `onAfterRoute`  but as asked I need it inside `onAfterInitialise`.

**Can anyone please post possible solution to get assigned template name in onAfterInitialise.
SQL , joomla method anything.** Thank you!

**UPDATE:** Any method from JFactory::getApplication when called within onAfterInitialise , resets your assigned template to default one. I doubt there is any solution to this since even if we call `$app->getMenu()->getActive()` to see assigned template our assigned template is reset to default one.

**This works only if SEF is OFF:**

```
/**
 * Get the assigned frontend template name
 *
 * @return  string  - template name
 */
public $assignedTemplate = '';

public function getAssignedTemplate() {

    $jinput   = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $current  =  $jinput->getInt('Itemid');

    $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery( true );

    $query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('m.template_style_id', 't.template')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__menu', 'm'))
    ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__template_styles', 't') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('m.template_style_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('t.id') . ')')
    ->where($db->quoteName('m.id') . ' = '.$current.'');


    // Make sure there aren't any errors
    try{

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $currentTemplate = $db->loadObjectList();
        if($currentTemplate){
            $this->assignedTemplate = $currentTemplate[0]->template;
        }
        //

    }catch (RuntimeException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    return $this->assignedTemplate;
}



public function onAfterInitialise() {

    echo $this->getAssignedTemplate();

}
```

Comment: what reason do it in `onAfterInitialise`? 
it not available in this time, so you need use DB query ... 

but, for any template manipulation I would suggest `onBeforeRender` or `onAfterDispatch`

Comment: When you say 3.x, which exact version of Joomla do you mean? Cause I see what you mean about Joomla 2.5, but in 3.3 it works fine

Comment: @Fedik I am not manipulating anything , I need the name of the assigned template that is all. And it should not switch template to default if used in onAfterInitialise

Comment: @Lodder 3.3 , it kicks me back to protostar, same as in 2.5.20 kicking back to beez. note , assign some other template to other page and go to it , it will kick it to default one. just updated to  3.3.1.rc.  same thing

Comment: @Fedik  I need to read assigned template xml file in onAfterInitialise and since it is kicking it to default one I dont have the assigned one info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may be wrong but I don't think it will work at all before the routing part is done. Simply because the active template depends on the routing.

If you want to do it in the `onAfterInitialise` event for whatever reason, you likely need to query the database table `#__menu` and read the `template_style_id` for the current `Itemid`.

Comment: It would work if the template would not be reset to default one. Try the code above I posted and you will see what I mean.

Comment: thnx for leading me to this. Yes it works via $jinput->getCmd('Itemid'). Bounty can be awarded in 22h

Comment: `$jinput->getInt('Itemid')` would even be a bit better since it always is an integer.

Comment: nice , will post the full sql

Comment: Will it work when Joomla SEF is enabled?

Comment: That's the whole point of the query. Without SEF you don't need it as the `Itemid` is available in the URL.

Comment: Just got disappointed, it wont work  with SEF on , only SEF off

Comment: Hmm, the `Itemid` may only be available after the routing is done as well. So you would have to look up that one first based on the alias?
Personally I would change the plugin so it triggers `onAfterRoute` and not `onAfterInitialise`. You could do without queries at all.

Comment: @Bakual I already have the plugin run check inside onAfterRoute , this here is the real issue http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/is-it-possible-to-change-system-plugin-fire-order-without-change-order-in-backen one plugin fires before mine and all the work is gone. 

Thing is I MUST read template.xml file to know what version it is and if the plugin should run. Like said , all I need is current assigned template name , but there is simply NO WAY, to do this in onafterinitialise. You mentioned alias ? Where could  I find it , in what method I mean?

Comment: The alias is stored together with the menu item. You can use either `alias` or `path` there to detect the menu item. But it will result in messy and complex code anyway. Basically you do some of the routing part in your system plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This works only if SEF is OFF

```
/**
 * Get the assigned frontend template name
 *
 * @return  string  - template name
 */
public $assignedTemplate = '';

public function getAssignedTemplate() {

    $jinput   = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $current  =  $jinput->getInt('Itemid');

    $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery( true );

    $query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('m.template_style_id', 't.template')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__menu', 'm'))
    ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__template_styles', 't') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('m.template_style_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('t.id') . ')')
    ->where($db->quoteName('m.id') . ' = '.$current.'');


    // Make sure there aren't any errors
    try{

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $currentTemplate = $db->loadObjectList();
        if($currentTemplate){
            $this->assignedTemplate = $currentTemplate[0]->template;
        }
        //

    }catch (RuntimeException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    return $this->assignedTemplate;
}



public function onAfterInitialise() {

    echo $this->getAssignedTemplate();

 }
```