# Is it possible to change system plugin fire order without change order in backend?

Tags: development, plugin

I have small issue with one of 3rd party system plugins that fires before my system plugin.
We both use `onAfterRoute` but if that plugin is ordered before mine, my  override is not taking place. 
I know that I can change the order of my plugin in backend and this way avoid the issue.

Thing I dont like is that I would need to do something like this in plugin  install.script.php to make sure my plugin always fires first

```
$q->set(array('enabled = 1','ordering = -1000'));
```

http://prntscr.com/3totid

Yes , it is an ugly hack and another issue is that admin can still change the order.

So the question is , is it possible to do this from the system plugin itself?
Something in `JDispatcher`  maybe to order my plugin first?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could imagine is if you have an second system plugin which does that in an earlier event like `onAfterInitialise`.
You would likely have to change it in the database directly then.

However imho, you should not do that at all. It's up to the system admin to decide in which order the plugins should fire. If your plugin needs to be first, tell the admin that she should check that.

Comment: we did exactly that and found out that the conflict plugin was doing something that it should not. it was rendering modules in onafterRoute. waiting for their fix.